# Can I make Firefox's Search Bar open page in new tab?

Tags: firefox, search

I'm using Firefox 3.5.3 with a Google as my default search.

When use the search toolbar at the top of the screen, is there a way to **show the search results in a *new* tab**?

Right now the search results overwrite the current page I am looking at. That is *rarely* what I want. I would like to see the results in a new tab.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is pretty easy.

> Type about:config into the address bar, and then put the following into the filter box: browser.search.openintab. Double-click the value to change it to true.

[Source](http://lifehacker.com/255171/firefox-tip-open-search-results-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: +3 if I could. This **really** helped me.

Comment: +1 for most correct answer. Though I personally wouldn't recommend doing that.

Comment: @hasen j - why wouldn't you recommend it?

Comment: I selected this answer because it is the best Firefox-only solution (no add-ons). I ended up using @alex's solution but I can only select one. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [TabMixPlus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122) for this. It can override the default behavior; it also has a lot of other features that you might find interesting and useful:

> Tab Mix Plus enhances Firefox's tab
>   browsing capabilities. It includes
>   such features as duplicating tabs,
>   controlling tab focus, tab clicking
>   options, undo closed tabs and windows,
>   plus much more. It also includes a
>   full-featured session manager.

Comment: I've been a long-time user of TabMixPlus but I never made the connection that it could control this. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help you! To be honest, TabMixPlus has so many features it's nearly impossible to know them all. I consider it a Swiss army knife of tabs :)

Comment: Agreed. It's one of the first add-ons I install after Firefox. It's rare that I can't find some combination features that let me get Firefox tabs working *exactly* the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

A few better options have been put here, but the lazy option is to just press CTRL-T to open a new tab before searching.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to changing any settings, you can just use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> when you search from the search box, or middle click the "search" icon to open the results in a new tab.  This way you can still search in the same tab if you want to, or open them in a new tab when that is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

[SearchLoad Options](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3544) is a Firefox Add-on that's highly rated and seems to do what you want.